# How to wrap a morph into a window in Pharo v3

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

I have built a game GUI made of morphs, all of them embeded into a rectangle morph. I want to wrap this rectangle morph into a window. How can i do this? I looked inside Spec but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a few ways, depending on your use case, but the easiest way is to send `#openInWindow` to your morph.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at what #openInWindow does, you'll get to

```
Morph>>openInWindowLabeled: aString inWorld: aWorld
```

where you can see how a `SystemWindow` is created and the morph is added to it. You might want to replace it by a `StandardWindow` if you need theming.